# Como evitar que un div o tabla dentro de un td se superponga al td "padre"

Tags: html, css

Tengo un `td`, con un color de fondo y un border-radius aplicado.

Mi idea es que la mitad superior tenga un color y la inferior otra, pero al colocar un `div` para hacer la división del `td`, y colocar un color de fondo, este se superpone al borde del `td`.

Este es mi código:

```html
<table width="100" height="100" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center" style="background-color: #FDD000; border-radius: 50px;">
      <div style="height: 50px; width: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #f5f5f5">

        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: imagen ejemplo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay dos formas: `overflow:hidden`; `border-radius:50px`.

En este caso, al contenedor `td` podrías agregarle un `overflow:hidden`:

```html
            
            <table width="100" height="100" align="center">
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="center" style="background-color: #FDD000; border-radius: 50px;overflow:hidden">
    <div style="height: 50px; width: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #f5f5f5">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

En este otro caso, más recomendable, se puede moldear al div y darle borde igual que al contenedor padre `td`:

```
border-top-left-radius: 50px;
border-top-right-radius: 50px;
```

```html
            
            <table width="100" height="100" align="center">
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="center" style="background-color: #FDD000; border-radius: 50px;">
    <div style="height: 50px; width: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #f5f5f5; border-top-left-radius:50px;border-top-right-radius:50px">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Esto se puede mejorar mucho más agregando un archivo de estilo css.

Comment: buenisimo, muchas gracias! me funcionó agregando overflow al td, en este caso es para un correo, por lo que agregar una hoja css no me es factible, :C 
Muchas GRACIAS!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograrlo dándole esquinas redondeadas en la parte superior izquierda y derecha con `border-top-left-radius: 50px` y `border-top-right-radius: 50px`:

```html
<table width="100" height="100" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center" style="background-color: #FDD000; border-radius: 50px;">
      <div style="height: 50px; width: 100px; overflow: hidden; border-top-left-radius: 50px; border-top-right-radius: 50px">
        <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #f5f5f5"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

O si gustas también usando `linear-gradient`:

```html
<table width="100" height="100" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center" style="background: linear-gradient(to top, #FDD000 50%, #f5f5f5 50%); border-radius: 50px;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```